# How to execute powershell scripts from MDT?

Tags: powershell, mdt

I have created MDT environment with PSD Extension by following these [steps](https://www.brookspeppin.com/2020/06/26/how-to-setup-powershell-deployment-extension-for-mdt-with-https/).

There is a default step for running a powershell script(Configure).

[image: configure]

I duplicated that and created Configure1.
[image: configure1]

And created a script in DeploymentShare scripts folder.
[image: scripts]

Just added below content to the powershell script I created.

```
#PSDConfigure1.ps1
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server' -name "fDenyTSConnections" -value 0
Enable-NetFirewallRule -DisplayGroup "Remote Desktop"
```

But it seems, the above content is not applied on the machine after task sequence.

Please suggest how to execute the powershell scripts.

Answer (score 0):

It could be because of execution policy.

Try this:

```
 %SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Noninteractive -Executionpolicy bypass -Noprofile -File {pathToFile.ps1}
```

Comment: Still same, it is not executing

Comment: It seems it is executed only if I keep in custo taks section.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @SaraJune, do you have proof the script is executing? Have you looked at the SMSTS log? I'd look in there to see if its being triggered properly. 
Default log location is here: %WINDIR%\TEMP\DeploymentLogs, and here is the technet article...
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/mem/configmgr/troubleshooting-reference